# Stop EF Core from using Merge to Insert

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am converting my application to .NET Core.  In doing so, I am running into issues with EF Core and inserts.

If I insert 1 or 2 rows then EF Core performs a normal SQL `INSERT` statement.

But when I have 3 or more rows, it switches to a `MERGE` statement, which then fails with:

> The column reference "inserted.MyKeyColumn" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.

My guess is that this is due to the fact that the query is actually running on a view that has an insert trigger on it to update the actual table(s) under the view.

Like I said, this works just fine when it uses insert statements.  But it fails when it tries to insert using a merge.

**Is there a way to stop EF Core from using `MERGE` for inserts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So some more research showed a way to force the use of single inserts:

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
        {
            options.MaxBatchSize(1);
        });
```

Warning: This will cause all inserts to be individual insert statements.  Not very performant for high volume inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Same error message, but different cause in EF core 7:

> The column reference "..." is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.

caused by a breaking change in EF core 7.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers
>
> By default, EF Core now saves changes via a significantly more efficient technique; unfortunately, this technique is not supported on SQL Server if the target table has database triggers, or **certain types of computed columns**.

the provided fix can be applied per table

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("SomeTrigger"));
}
```

The "SomeTrigger" can be any string.