# INSERTED table gives an error when using a view with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to run the following merge statement to insert a row:

```
MERGE sales.Widget 
USING (
    VALUES ('19668651', 4.75))
    AS widg (WidgetId, WidgetCost) 
    ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (WidgetId, WidgetCost)
    VALUES (widg.WidgetId, widg.WidgetCost)
OUTPUT INSERTED.WidgetId
    INTO @inserted;
GO
```

I am confused by the error I am getting:

> The column reference "inserted.WidgetId" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.

I thought that the `inserted` table was just an in-memory table of the values being passed in to the merge statement.

Why then would it care if I am modifying a "base" table as long as the value was passed in?

I can clearly tell that this is related to the fact that I have a view with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on it (because it works fine against a normal table).

**But why does SQL Server not just return the value that was passed in?** (WidgetId in this case.)

---

Here is the script to reproduce the error:

```
CREATE SCHEMA sales
GO

-- Create the base table
CREATE TABLE sales.Widget_OLD(
    WIDGET_ID int NOT NULL,
    WIDGET_COST money NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Widget PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (WIDGET_ID ASC) 
) 
GO

-- Create the overlay view
CREATE VIEW sales.Widget AS
    SELECT  widg.WIDGET_ID AS WidgetId, widg.WIDGET_COST AS WidgetCost
    FROM    sales.Widget_OLD widg
GO

-- create the instead of insert trigger

CREATE TRIGGER sales.InsertWidget ON sales.Widget
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sales.Widget_OLD (WIDGET_ID, WIDGET_COST)
    SELECT  Inserted.WidgetId, inserted.WidgetCost
    FROM    Inserted
END
GO

DECLARE @inserted TABLE (WidgetId varchar(11) NOT null);

MERGE sales.Widget 
USING (
    VALUES ('19668651', 4.75))
    AS widg (WidgetId, WidgetCost) 
    ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (WidgetId, WidgetCost)
    VALUES (widg.WidgetId, widg.WidgetCost)
OUTPUT INSERTED.WidgetId
    INTO @inserted;
GO

-- Clean up
DROP TRIGGER sales.InsertWidget 
DROP VIEW sales.Widget
DROP TABLE sales.Widget_OLD
DROP SCHEMA sales
go
```

NOTE: This is from my Entity Framework Core application when I try to do 3+ inserts ([see this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183119/stop-ef-core-from-using-merge-to-insert))  That question is about how to stop EF Core from using `MERGE`.  This one is to understand what is happening.

Comment: "But why does SQL Server not just return the value that was passed in?" Because `inserted` doesn't refer to the values passed in but to the values *actually inserted*. In other words, it has to defer producing these values until the trigger has actually determined what they are. This is much different from just coughing up the input, even if, in this case, the trigger happens not to change the value, and apparently complicated enough that this particular scenario isn't supported.

Comment: Also, why are you using `merge` for what can be done with a simple `insert`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - **Short Answer:** This is generated code.  **Longish Answer:** A product called Entity Framework Core (by Microsoft) generates code like this for inserts when there is more than 3 rows to insert.  I have simplified down to one row for this question, but the original query inserted 3 rows via the Merge. **Longer Answer:** See the link at the bottom of the question for the full details and the workaround (as an answer).